# Chose File In Webview 4.2.2 (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-webview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I try to input the image file in my html page in webview 4.2.2
   
But the input file does not work. Do you have the solution for my problem ?
please help me

**This is my code (Tambah.java) :**

```
public class Tambah extends Activity {

private TextView text2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tambah);

    final WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webPage);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.104/safa/tambah");
    myWebView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                WebView myWebView = (WebView) v;

                switch(keyCode)
                {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                        if(myWebView.canGoBack())
                        {
                            myWebView.goBack();
                            return true;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have internet permission declared in manifest ?

Comment: I have already declared,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override the `onShowFileChooser` method in your `WebChromeClient` like below:

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("*/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

And then `onActivityResult` do the following:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            //Uri result = intent.getData();
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                    : intent.getData();
            if(result != null){
                Uri[] resultsArray = new Uri[1];
                resultsArray[0] = result;
                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(resultsArray);
            }
            else
                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);

        }
    }
```

and define a static int for your request code in your activity like:

```
private static final int PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
```

It should work like charm.

Comment: Thank you very much @Rahul Sharma, you have helped me. This code works for me.

Comment: @dickynugrohohidayatulloh please accept the answer then. :)